# Show that estimator $\bar{X}-1$ is unbiased estimator if $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are random samples from given distribution

Tags: expected-value, unbiased-estimator

So, the distribution for samples $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ is given as $$f(x|\theta) = \left \{ \begin{aligned} e^{-(x-\theta)}, \ \ \theta < x < \infty \\ 0, \text{ otherwise.} \end{aligned} \right.$$

So, I guess, I should show that $E(\bar{X}-1) = \bar{X}$? $$E(\bar{X}-1) = E(\bar{X}) - E(1) = E\left(\frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{n}\right) - 1 = \frac{1}{n}\bar{X} -1 \Rightarrow \text{ the estimator is biased.}$$

Comment: $\bar{X}-1$ most certainly is biased for $\mu$! You've made a mistake for the expression after that last $=$ sign, but I think you know how to fix it. Other than that, your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Unbiased for what? Should be $E(\bar{X}-1) =E(\bar X)-1= E(X_1)-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the expectation in question cannot be equal to $\bar{X}$, since that is a random variable.  (Your present working confuses the estimator with the parameter of interest.)  From the specified distribution, the expected value of a single observation is:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(X_i)
&= \int \limits_\mathbb{R} x f(x|\theta) dx \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_\theta^\infty x e^{-(x-\theta)} dx \\[6pt]
&= e^\theta \int \limits_\theta^\infty x e^{-x} dx. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Now, using integration by parts, you have:

$$\int \limits_\theta^\infty x e^{-x} dx 
= - x e^{-x} \bigg|_\theta^\infty + \int \limits_\theta^\infty e^{-x} dx 
= \theta e^{-\theta} + e^{-\theta} 
= e^{-\theta} \cdot (\theta+1).$$

You therefore have $\mathbb{E}(X_i) = e^\theta e^{-\theta} \cdot (\theta+1) = \theta+1$. 
 Applying this to your estimator, you get:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(\bar{X} - 1)
&= \mathbb{E}(\bar{X}) - 1 \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}(X_i) -1 \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (\theta+1) -1 \\[6pt]
&= \theta+1 - 1 \\[6pt]
&= \theta. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

So as you can see, the estimator $\bar{X} - 1$ is unbiased for the parameter $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

The estimator is unbiased for $\theta$. It wouldn't make sense to say it's unbiased for $\bar{X}$ or anything related to it, because $\bar{X}$ is itself a random variable.

Proof of unbiasness as below:

$E \bar{X} = E X_1 = \int_{\theta}^{\infty} xe^{-(x-\theta)}dx$

$= \int_0^\infty (u+\theta)e^{-u}du \quad$ (let $u = x-\theta$)

$= \int_0^\infty ue^{-u}du + \theta  \int_0^\infty e^{-u}du$

$= 1 + \theta$

$\Rightarrow E(\bar{X} - 1) = \theta$

Note that $X$ is just an $Exp(1)$ random variable with a shift of 1.